# ExpressionEngine - Zoo Visitor Plugin Questions

Tags: zoo-visitor

This is more of a question before I buy as I can't find any answers online and would like feedback from people who use it.

A client wants to create a member's only section where they can download files and also only access a secure "news" section that's just for members to view. Is this possible with this plugin?

I see that the documentation speaks about member profiles etc but I couldn't find any info about using it to create custom systems?

Thanks for any info/advice,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is perfectly possible to do without using Zoo Visitor.

To create a "members only" section of your website you only need to specify that the template(s) is/are only accessible to a particular member group. Or you could use some conditional logic with a template to show/hide content based on member groups.

The advantage that Zoo Visitor gives is that it will create an entry for each member account. This entry can have additional field types that it's not possible to add to a normal member account.